# What component manages the permissions in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel

Perhaps it's a silly question, but I would like to customize how permissions are managed in Linux (specifically Debian in this case if that makes a difference). I would like to define the permissions (possibly by writing custom kernel module?) by attaching them directly to the process/executable rather than to a specific user/group/whatever that triggered the process. This automatically means that the traditional `chmod` is just not good enough. Is there some specific kernel module I can look at to see how the traditional rwx permissions are managed to customize it a bit? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: [Linux Security Modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Security_Modules). Also have a look at SELinux/AppArmor which use LSM and may be similar to what you have in mind. Of course, I absolutely do not recommend to implement any such module yourself. The risk of creating a vulnerability is much larger than whatever benefit it has.

Comment: man. I recently started writing my own OS in my free time and so far it works like a charm! I think I could take it :D But yes, LSM does look interesting. I honestly don't know how I was supposed to google for this. Thank you!

Comment: Even the LSM integrated in the mainline kernel that have been developed for a long time by kernel developers have serious vulnerabilities found in them, making it a non-trivial question whether their benefits out-weight the additional attack surface.

Comment: Are you talking about the "umask" ?

Comment: Also have a look at getfacl

Comment: thank you. That's an interesting tool, but it doesn't look like what i'm looking for